# Why am I getting [object object ] instead of JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making an API. When I send correct data for login, I get JSON but when I send incorrect data, I get this [object object] message, why?

When the correct information is provided.

Here is my code.

```
router.route('/login').post(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('i should be here when path match to login', req.body);

    UserModel.findOne({
        username: req.body.username,
      })
      .exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        if (user) {
          var passwordMatch = passwordHash.verify(req.body.password, user.password);
          if (passwordMatch) {
            var token = generateToken(user);
            res.status(200).json({
              user: user,
              token: token
            });
          } else {
            next({
              message: "password didnot match",
              status: 400
            })
          }
        } else {
          next({
            message: 'Invalid Username',
            status: 400
          })
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: getting [Object object] only by sending incorrect data?

Comment: `UserModel.findOne({
    username: req.body.username,
  })` is failing to find the username from DB and you are not catching or returning any response for that. That may be the reason

Comment: `[Object object]` means you have received an `object`. The value of type usually returned when you either concatinate the `object` with `string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `[Object object]` has nothing to do with the data you sent. This has to do with the way you print the value.

`[Object object]` means you have received an object. The value of type usually returned when you either concatinate the `object` with `string`.

Example:

```js
var obj = {a: 1};
console.log('Printing ' + obj); // Prints [object object]
```

So, instead of concatinating the `object`, you can `stringify` the object and print it.

Example

```js
var obj = {a: 1};
console.log('Printing ' + JSON.stringify(obj)); // Prints {"a":1}
```

Or

```js
var obj = {a: 1};
console.log('Printing ', obj); // Prints formatted {"a":1}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the whole stuff. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 res.status(200).json({
              user: user,
              token: token
            });
```

This is how you are sending on success. You are formatting response as JSON.
But on failure, you are returning plain JS Object. Formatting failure responses as JSON object will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using next. Try this code, It will work straight away!

```
router.route('/login').post(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('i should be here when path match to login', req.body);

        UserModel.findOne({
            username: req.body.username,
          })
          .exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(500).json({message:'Backend error'})
            }
            if (user) {
              var passwordMatch = passwordHash.verify(req.body.password, user.password);
              if (passwordMatch) {
                var token = generateToken(user);
                res.status(200).json({
                  user: user,
                  token: token,
                  message:'Login successful'
                });
              } else {
                res.status(400).json({message:'Wrong password'})
              }
            } else {
              res.status(400).json({message:'User does not exist'})
            }
          });
      });
```